# How to copy all values from data grid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have to export datagrid values to Excel. Iam using following code to copy datagrid values.

```
InvoiceDataGrid.SelectAllCells()
InvoiceDataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(Nothing, Me.InvoiceDataGrid)
Dim result1 As String = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
InvoiceDataGrid.UnselectAllCells()
```

But some times it do not fetch the integer values from the grid. Please help me. .

Answer (score 3):

This is something that I have written and use in C#...

**ExportToExcel**

```
private void ExportToExcel()
{
    try
    {
        dataGrid.SelectAllCells();
        dataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid);
        var resultat = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
        var result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        dataGrid.UnselectAllCells();
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        var excelFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\"+Environment.UserName+@"\Desktop\exportedcompanies.xls");
        excelFile.WriteLine(result.Replace(',', ' '));
        excelFile.Close();           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. It is working but the date format is changed. I have a date format in grid as dd/mm/yy but in excel sheet it converted as dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm. .  How can i resolve this problem .

Comment: @PrabhagaranP You'll probably want to loop through the `DataGridRows` and format the columns using `String.Format(dd/MM/yy);`